# Deploying a go service from a monorepo of shared modules

Tags: docker, go, deployment, monorepo

I recently merged multiple go services into a monorepo with shared libraries which looks like this:

```
root    
├── services
│   ├── svc1
│   │   ├── main.go
│   │   ├── go.mod
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── svc 2
│       ├── main.go
│       ├── go.mod
│       └── Dockerfile
└── libs
    ├── lib1  
    │   ├── lib.go  
    │   └── go.mod
    └── lib2
        ├── lib.go 
        └── go.mod
```

Now, the services use the `replace` keyword in their respective `go.mod` files in order to import the libraries locally like so:

```
module example.com/services/svc1

go 1.20

require (
    example.com/libs/lib1 v0.0.0
)

replace example.com/libs/lib1 v0.0.0 => ../../libs/lib1
```

However, this has caused me some trouble in deploying the microservices individually since:

1. Docker cannot copy items from outside the build context
2. If a shared library only exists on a branch (eg: a dev branch) other than the main branch, go mod cannot download it.

I have tried to make different dockerfiles for each service that exist in the root directory of the repo in order to copy the entire monorepo into the docker container for each build. But this method of doing things is highly inefficient.

I would like to deploy each microservice individually with only the libraries it needs. For example: `svc1` might require `lib1` but `svc2` might require both `lib1` and `lib2`

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.